# Is there any way that I can add a small overlay on the safari browser while user is browsing the internet?

Tags: ios, iphone, background-process, multitasking, springboard

Basically, I want to build an iOS app that can run in the background and can play audio/video or show a slideshow in a small overlay. I have not found anything in the apple documentation. The closest I found is this,

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Any lead would be appreciated. But, I don't want to do jailbreak.

Answer (score 0):

You can't overlay anything over apple's Safari, but you can certainly create your own browser app that has this feature.

Creating a copy of Apple's Safari (at least the most basic features) is pretty simple with the `UIWebView`.